# c++ warning: expected a declaration

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I implemented a c++ function in a template class `Valli<I>`. I am using the Visual C++ IDE. There is always an error on `while` which is:

```
expected a declaration
```

I checked the code once and once again,and didn't find out anything wrong.

```
template<class I>
void Valli<I>::insert(I& new_item){
    int front=0;
    int rear=links.size()-1;
    int mid=(front+rear)/2;

    //this while loop binsearches the vector<iterator>
    while(rear!=front){
        if(new_item>links[mid]*){
        front=mid;
        mid=(front+rear)/2;
        }else{
            if(new_item<links[mid]*){
            rear=mid;
            mid=(front+rear)/2;
            }else{

            rear=mid;
            front=mid;
            }
        }
    }
...
...
}
```

Comment: How about the "enter code here"?

Comment: can you paste the whole compiler error from your output window?

Comment: What is the trailing * for in the "if" statement?